# Proving by induction on $n$ that $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n (k+1)2^{k} = n2^{n+1} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Alright so here is what I've got so far.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)2^{k} = n2^{n+1} $$

---

**Base Case:** ($n = 1$)

LHS:

$\sum \limits_{k=1}^n (k+1)2^{k} = (2)2^{1} = 4 $

RHS:

$\ n2^{n+1} = 1(2^{2}) = 4 $

LHS = RHS

---

**Inductive Case:**

LHS for $n+1$

$\sum \limits_{k=1}^n (k+1)2^{k} + ((n+1) +1)2^{n+1} $

---

I'm not sure how to progress from here.

I am a complete beginner to induction and this as far as I could make it with my notes.

My best guess is to use induction hypothesis but I'm not sure how that works.

If you could explain your steps and the reasoning behind them I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hint: It's a good idea to write down what we're assuming and what we're trying to show for the inductive step. For the inductive step, we are assuming that $\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(k+1)2^k}=n2^{n+1}$ for some particular $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, and we want to show that $\sum\limits _{k=1}^{n+1}(k+1)2^k = (n+1)2^{n+2}$, i.e. that $\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(k+1)2^k} + (n+2)2^{n+1} = (n+1)2^{n+2}$. We want to use our induction assumption to help us show this. Can you think of a way to do so?

Comment: I don't follow,could you elaborate?

Comment: Basically, for the inductive step, we want to show that $\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)2^{k}} + (n+2)2^{n+1} = (n+1)2^{n+2}$, under the assumption that $\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)2^{k}} = \color{teal}{n2^{n+1}}$, for some particular $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. **Because we have this assumption**, we can see that $$\begin{align*}\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)2^{k}} + (n+2)2^{n+1}  &= \color{teal}{n2^{n+1}} + (n+2)2^{n+1}\\&=\cdots \end{align*}$$(simplify using algebra rules to get down to the right-hand side of the equation we are trying to show).

Comment: That explains it! Because I didn't write out my assumption, I didn't realize I could substitute like that. Is this substitution step called Induction Hypothesis, or is that different? Thanks for clearing it up great explanation!

Comment: This is quite a typical sort of induction proof, it may be helpful for you if you have access to some sample induction proofs so that you can read them and get an idea of how they work.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, you could call it the Induction Hypothesis (often it is referred to as the ''inductive hypothesis'' or ''induction assumption'' also), and you are allowed to use this assumption to prove the required equation (in fact, this is basically the whole point of induction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

It always a very good idea to write down, very clearly, three things in an induction proof:

- Your base case
- Your inductive hypothesis (the case you assume holds)
- What you need to prove in your induction step (the $n+1$ case if the hypothesis is the $n$ case)

Another good idea for induction is always remember that this "induction hypothesis" is key to the whole mess - it basically means "the previous case implies the next, which with the base case lets us prove infinitely many cases." In other words, you need to do whatever you can to try to make your inductive hypothesis applicable - in a proof like this, you want to manipulate your $n+1$ case into revealing the $n$ case. And then since you assume the $n$ case holds, you can substitute values as necessary, and use that to try and prove the $n+1$ case.

You made some errors in your $n+1$ equation as well which lent itself to problems. Usually if you assume the $n$ case holds you just replace every $n$ with $n+1$ in the inductive step when you want to see what you need to show.

That re-emphasizes the point of writing down the three things clearly.

---

**Solution:**

Let's assume the base case as you give in the OP is valid. If we make the inductive hypothesis that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)2^k = n2^{n+1}$$

then we want to show in our induction step that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (k+1)2^k = (n+1)2^{n+1+1} = (n+1)2^{n+2}$$

(Just replace all the $n$'s with $n+1$ here!) We note: we can split up the sum into the $1,2,...,n$ sum and basically "drag out" the $n+1$ term by itself:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (k+1)2^k = (n+1+1)2^{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)2^k = (n+2)2^{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)2^k$$

Invoking our inductive hypothesis and doing some factoring, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
(n+2)2^{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)2^k &= (n+2)2^{n+1}+n2^{n+1}\\
&=2^{n+1}(2n+2) \\
&=2^{n+1}\cdot 2 (n+1)\\
&= 2^{n+2}(n+1) \end{align}$$

completing the proof.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} (k+1)2^k & = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)2^k + (n+2) 2^{n+1}. \\ & = n2^{n+1} + (n+2)2^{n+1}. \\ & = (2n+2)2^{n+1}. \\ & = (n+1)2^{n+2}. \end{align}$$

Proving the result for $n+1.$

Comment: Could you explain your second step where you get n2^(n+1)+(n+2)2^(n+1). How did you get n2^(n+1) on the left side of the plus sign? What is the logic and how does that work?Thanks!

Comment: In the second step I have used induction hypothesis.

Comment: While using induction we first prove it for base case. Then if it correct we assume that the formula is correct for $n^th$ case. Then we prove that it is correct for (n+1)th case. It is that assumption which he used in the second step.

Comment: As induction formulas are true for only Natural numbers and we have shown that it is true for 1 and n+1. So it will be true for all natural numbers.